# Ignore whitespace in Regex expression and match

Tags: c#, json, regex

I need to read some data from corrupt Json that can't be parsed to an object. I need to use regex to get this. I have one final thing that is causing me trouble. Here is a snippet of the Json I am working with.

```
price: "1129.0",
quantity: "0",
rating: "4.9",
ratingCount: "127",
```

I want to extract `4.9`. To do this I have the following Regex.

```
(?<=rating: \")([\s\S]*?)(?=\")
```

The problem I have is that sometimes the Json is missing whitespace between the colon.

```
price:"1129.0",
quantity:"0",
rating:"4.9",
ratingCount:"127",
```

I cant modify the source content as there is a need to preserve whitespace within some of the nodes. I tried to be super specific and used the following

```
(?<=rating: \")([\S*\s*][0-9.](.*?))(?=\")
```

This works, but yet again, If I have json that is missing the whitespace, it does not work. If I remove the whitespace in the rule itself, it also does not work. I need to be able to use a rule that does not care if there is any whitespace in the start and end block. So long as everything other than the whitespace matches, it is good.

I am using C# to execute these regex rules and have been using https://regexr.com/3qvlp to test the rules out.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html

Comment: Try `(?<=rating:\s*\").*(?=\",)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/kgIDGR/1

Comment: You're using un-needed assertions. This is a very bad way to write regex. It's slow, it has pitfalls that might be problematic. Since you're capturing anyway, just drop the assertions. `rating\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?<=rating:\s*\")([\S*\s*][0-9.](.*?))(?=\")` should work. It adds an optional whitespace before the " that is variable length. If you only want one or zero, then `(?<=rating:\s{0,1}\")([\S*\s*][0-9.](.*?))(?=\")` will work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i have tried this and it doesnt seem to work https://regexr.com/3qvlp

Comment: Interesting, I have the exact same thing and it works for me. I also tested it in c# code and it works for me. https://regexr.com/3r0d1

Comment: regexr does not use the .net flavor of regex; while the .net version of regex supports quantifiers in lookbehinds as you are using here, their version may not. Use regexstorm to test .net regexes if you see an error you don't expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `\s*` in the positive lookbehind the match zero or more whitespace characters and match not a `"` using a negated character class `[^"]+`:

[`(?<=rating:\s*")[^"]+(?=\")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3drating%3a%5cs*%22%29%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5c%22%29&i=price%3a+%221129.0%22%2c%0d%0aquantity%3a+%220%22%2c%0d%0arating%3a+%224.9%22%2c%0d%0aratingCount%3a+%22127%22%2c%0d%0a%0d%0aprice%3a%221129.0%22%2c%0d%0aquantity%3a%220%22%2c%0d%0arating%3a%224.9%22%2c%0d%0aratingCount%3a%22127%22%2c)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XHC41299)